# Bootstrap,nav,nav-pills,image,image vertical align

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to make one menu:

[image: I want like this]

Now,I have problem,how can I make the images vertical align to bottom? Variable image sizes.

Now it looks like (Too big is the images,the space beettwen image/span/text):

[image: Too big is the images,the space beettwen image/span/text]

The code:

```css
.vehicletype{
width:90%;
line-height:70px;
margin-right:5%;
margin-left:5%;
margin-top:5%;
}
.vehicletype img{
 vertical-align:bottom;
}
.vehicletype a{
 vertical-align:top;
}
.vehicletype ul li {
float:left;
width:12.5%;
list-style:none;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:14pt;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-stretch:semi-condensed;
 font-weight:bold;
}

.vehicletype ul li a{
width:100%;
color:rgba(200,54,55,1);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) 
          brightness(135%)
          contrast(120%);
  filter: grayscale(100%) 
          brightness(135%)
          contrast(120%);
  transition: filter 0.1s, box-shadow 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: filter 0.1s, -webkit-filter 0.1s, box-shadow 0.1s;


}
.vehicletype ul li a:hover img{
 width:100%;
 color:rgba(200,54,55,1);
 filter:none;
 -webkit-filter:none;
 text-decoration:none;

}
.vehicletype ul li a:hover{
 filter:none;
 -webkit-filter:none;
 text-decoration:none;
} 
.vehicletype ul li a img{
 width:100%;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-left:auto;
 padding-right:5%;
 padding-left:5%;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) 
          brightness(135%)
          contrast(120%);
  filter: grayscale(100%) 
          brightness(135%)
          contrast(120%);
  
  transition: filter 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: filter 0.3s, -webkit-filter 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  
}
.vehicletype ul li a img:hover{
 filter:none;
 -webkit-filter:none;
}

.menuspan{
 width:90%;
 height:8px;
 border-radius:4px;
 background-color:rgba(200,54,55,1);
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) 
          brightness(165%)
          contrast(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%) 
          brightness(165%)
          contrast(100%);
  transition: filter 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: filter 0.3s, -webkit-filter 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  margin-top:5%;
  margin-left:5%;
  margin-right:5%;
}
.vehicletype ul li .active a{
filter:none;
-webkit-filter:none;
}
.vehicletype ul li .active img{
filter:none;
-webkit-filter:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="vehicletype">
<ul class="vehicletypes">
 

 
 <li ><a href="?vehicletype=car">
 <img src="http://pastorautoservis.com/sunday/theme/default/img/car1.png">
    <div class="menuspan"></div>Car</a></li>
 <li><a href="?vehicletype=van">
 
  <img src="http://pastorautoservis.com/sunday/theme/default/img/van1.png">
 
 <div class="menuspan"></div>Van</a></li>
    <li><a href="?vehicletype=truck">
    <img src="http://pastorautoservis.com/sunday/theme/default/img/truck1.png">
    <div class="menuspan"></div>Truck</a></li>
    <li><a href="?vehicletype=bus">
     <img src="http://pastorautoservis.com/sunday/theme/default/img/bus1.png">
 
    <div class="menuspan"></div>Bus</a></li>
    <li><a href="?vehicletype=motobike">
        <img src="http://pastorautoservis.com/sunday/theme/default/img/motobike1.png">
 <div class="menuspan"></div>motobike</a></li>
     <li><a href="?vehicletype=boat">
        <img src="http://pastorautoservis.com/sunday/theme/default/img/boat1.png">
  <div class="menuspan"></div>boat</a></li>
      <li><a href="?vehicletype=oldtimer">
        <img src="http://pastorautoservis.com/sunday/theme/default/img/oldtimer1.png">
 <div class="menuspan"></div>oldtimer</a></li>
       <li><a href="?vehicletype=other">
        <img src="http://pastorautoservis.com/sunday/theme/default/img/other1.png">
    <div class="menuspan"></div>other</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was testing your code, and my suggestion is that you need to set a width/height for each image or resize the images. About the space between the text and image is easy, only you need is change the line-height:70px from vehicleType class.

I'll hope I help you!

```css
.vehicletype{
width:90%;
line-height:40px;
margin-right:5%;
margin-left:5%;
margin-top:5%;
}

.car img{height:21px;}
.van img{height:32px;}
.truck img{}
.bus img{height:38px;}
.moto img{height:21px;}
.boat img{height:30px;}
.old img{height:19px;}
.other img{height:21px;}

.vehicletype img{
 vertical-align:bottom;
}
.vehicletype a{
 vertical-align:top;
    display:block;
}
.vehicletype ul li {
float:left;
width:12.5%;
list-style:none;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:14pt;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-stretch:semi-condensed;
 font-weight:bold;
}

.vehicletype ul li a{
width:100%;
color:rgba(200,54,55,1);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) 
          brightness(135%)
          contrast(120%);
  filter: grayscale(100%) 
          brightness(135%)
          contrast(120%);
  transition: filter 0.1s, box-shadow 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: filter 0.1s, -webkit-filter 0.1s, box-shadow 0.1s;


}
.vehicletype ul li a:hover img{
 width:auto;
    max-width:100%;
 color:rgba(200,54,55,1);
 filter:none;
 -webkit-filter:none;
 text-decoration:none;

}
.vehicletype ul li a:hover{
 filter:none;
 -webkit-filter:none;
 text-decoration:none;
} 
.vehicletype ul li a img{
 width:auto;
    max-width:100%;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-left:auto;
 padding-right:5%;
 padding-left:5%;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) 
          brightness(135%)
          contrast(120%);
  filter: grayscale(100%) 
          brightness(135%)
          contrast(120%);
  
  transition: filter 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: filter 0.3s, -webkit-filter 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  
}
.vehicletype ul li a img:hover{
 filter:none;
 -webkit-filter:none;
}

.menuspan{
 width:90%;
 height:8px;
 border-radius:4px;
 background-color:rgba(200,54,55,1);
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) 
          brightness(165%)
          contrast(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%) 
          brightness(165%)
          contrast(100%);
  transition: filter 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: filter 0.3s, -webkit-filter 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  margin-top:5%;
  margin-left:5%;
  margin-right:5%;
}
.vehicletype ul li .active a{
filter:none;
-webkit-filter:none;
}
.vehicletype ul li .active img{
filter:none;
-webkit-filter:none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="vehicletype">
<ul class="vehicletypes">
 

 
 <li class="car"><a href="?vehicletype=car">
 <img src="http://pastorautoservis.com/sunday/theme/default/img/car1.png" >
    <div class="menuspan"></div>Car</a></li>
 <li class="van"><a href="?vehicletype=van">
 
  <img src="http://pastorautoservis.com/sunday/theme/default/img/van1.png">
 
 <div class="menuspan"></div>Van</a></li>
    <li class="truck"><a href="?vehicletype=truck">
    <img src="http://pastorautoservis.com/sunday/theme/default/img/truck1.png">
    <div class="menuspan"></div>Truck</a></li>
    <li class="bus"><a href="?vehicletype=bus">
     <img src="http://pastorautoservis.com/sunday/theme/default/img/bus1.png">
 
    <div class="menuspan"></div>Bus</a></li>
    <li class="moto"><a href="?vehicletype=motobike">
        <img src="http://pastorautoservis.com/sunday/theme/default/img/motobike1.png">
 <div class="menuspan"></div>motobike</a></li>
     <li class="boat"><a href="?vehicletype=boat">
        <img src="http://pastorautoservis.com/sunday/theme/default/img/boat1.png">
  <div class="menuspan"></div>boat</a></li>
      <li class="old"><a href="?vehicletype=oldtimer">
        <img src="http://pastorautoservis.com/sunday/theme/default/img/oldtimer1.png">
 <div class="menuspan"></div>oldtimer</a></li>
       <li class="other"><a href="?vehicletype=other">
        <img src="http://pastorautoservis.com/sunday/theme/default/img/other1.png">
    <div class="menuspan"></div>other</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To today it was worked perfectly,now again is not good. :/
A code:

```css
@media(min-width:768px){
.vehicletype{
width:95%;
line-height:40px;
margin-right:5%;
margin-left:5%;
margin-top:5%;
}

.car img{height:21px;}
.van img{height:32px;}
.truck img{height:32px;}
.bus img{height:38px;}
.moto img{height:21px;}
.boat img{height:30px;}
.old img{height:19px;}
.other img{height:21px;}

.vehicletype img{
 vertical-align:bottom;
}
.vehicletype a{
 vertical-align:top;
    display:block;
}
.vehicletype ul li {
float:left;
width:12.5%;
list-style:none;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:14pt;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-stretch:semi-condensed;
 font-weight:bold;
}

.vehicletype ul li a{
width:100%;
color:rgba(200,54,55,1);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) 
          brightness(135%)
          contrast(120%);
  filter: grayscale(100%) 
          brightness(135%)
          contrast(120%);
  transition: filter 0.1s, box-shadow 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: filter 0.1s, -webkit-filter 0.1s, box-shadow 0.1s;


}
.vehicletype ul li a:hover img{
 width:auto;
    max-width:100%;
 color:rgba(200,54,55,1);
 filter:none;
 -webkit-filter:none;
 text-decoration:none;

}
.vehicletype ul li a:hover{
 filter:none;
 -webkit-filter:none;
 text-decoration:none;
} 
.vehicletype ul li a img{
 width:auto;
    max-width:100%;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-left:auto;
 padding-right:5%;
 padding-left:5%;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) 
          brightness(135%)
          contrast(120%);
  filter: grayscale(100%) 
          brightness(135%)
          contrast(120%);
  
  transition: filter 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: filter 0.3s, -webkit-filter 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  
}
.vehicletype ul li a img:hover{
 filter:none;
 -webkit-filter:none;
}

.menuspan{
 width:90%;
 height:8px;
 border-radius:4px;
 background-color:rgba(200,54,55,1);
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) 
          brightness(165%)
          contrast(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%) 
          brightness(165%)
          contrast(100%);
  transition: filter 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: filter 0.3s, -webkit-filter 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  margin-top:5%;
  margin-left:5%;
  margin-right:5%;
}
.vehicletype ul li .active a{
filter:none;
-webkit-filter:none;
}
.vehicletype ul li .active img{
filter:none;
-webkit-filter:none;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
<div class="vehicletype col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
<ul class="vehicletypes" id="vehicletypes">
 <li class="car col-xs-6 l" ><a href="?vehicletype=car">
 <img src="http://origomalta.com/theme/default/img/car1.png" >
    <div class="menuspan"></div>Car</a></li>
 <li class="van col-xs-6 r"><a href="?vehicletype=van">
 
  <img src="http://origomalta.com/theme/default/img/van1.png">
 
 <div class="menuspan"></div>Van</a></li>
    <li class="truck col-xs-6 l"><a href="?vehicletype=truck">
    <img src="http://origomalta.com/theme/default/img/truck1.png">
    <div class="menuspan"></div>Truck</a></li>
    <li class="bus col-xs-6 r"><a href="?vehicletype=bus">
     <img src="http://origomalta.com/theme/default/img/bus1.png">
 
    <div class="menuspan"></div>Bus</a></li>
    <li class="moto col-xs-6 l"><a href="?vehicletype=moto">
        <img src="http://origomalta.com/theme/default/img/motobike1.png">
 <div class="menuspan"></div>motobike</a></li>
     <li class="boat col-xs-6 r"><a href="?vehicletype=boat">
        <img src="http://origomalta.com/theme/default/img/boat1.png">
  <div class="menuspan"></div>boat</a></li>
      <li class="old col-xs-6 l"><a href="?vehicletype=oldtimer">
        <img src="http://origomalta.com/theme/default/img/oldtimer1.png">
 <div class="menuspan"></div>oldtimer</a></li>
       <li class="other col-xs-6 r"><a href="?vehicletype=other">
        <img src="http://origomalta.com/theme/default/img/other1.png">
    <div class="menuspan"></div>other</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

There is working good,but,inside a website no. :/